# How long do you have to undelete your post?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-answer, deleted-questions, deleting-posts

I'd like to know how long I have to change my mind if I delete one of my posts. I deleted some of my sandbox questions several weeks ago and they're still there, but I don't know how long they stay or if the same rules apply to the main site.

Also, I presume that once you delete a post that other people cannot see it (even though you still see it in red), but does this apply to moderators as well?

Comment: `I'd like to know how long I have to change my mind if I delete one of my posts.` - until SE shuts down. If you self-deleted, you can undelete it at any time. If it was deleted after being closed, it takes (at least?) 3 undeletion votes to get it back. If it was deleted by a moderator, I think you need to mod flag to get it undeleted. Mods can delete and undelete with a single vote regardless of the state. If you delete a post, moderators and users with the privilege to see deleted posts (usually unlocked at 10k) can see it. OP can always see their own deleted posts

Comment: Generally, looking aside exceptions, a post can be undeleted at any time. Who can do it depends on how it was deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions can be deleted at any time as long as they have no answers.

Deleted posts can be seen by moderators and users with the right privilege.

Excessive deletion of content can be sanctioned, as the content belongs to the community.

To make a post completely disappear, ask a moderator to redact it.